# Accumulating unique answers

Tags: python-3.x

My program carries out calculations. Some of the results are the same as others. I want to accumulate, or at least count, each result, but not any that have gone before.

For example,
 a = 2 + 2
 b = 1 + 3

They both give 4, but I want to count only the first one. I'm trying to count only the results that are distict from the others.

Algorithmically,

```
a = b + c
if a != (a result that has already come up):
    count += 1
```

If figure I'll have to accumulate the results somewhere so the program will be able to check the new result against all those that have been stored somewhere somehow.

Can anyone help? I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: you could use `set`s just add the result to a set and then count the `set` size at the end

Answer (score 0):

you can store the result of the calculation in a list / set, and check if the result has already appeared in a previous calculation and increment counter.

```
results = []
count = 0
a = b + c
if a not in results:
    count += 1
    results.append(a)
```

Comment: I'd seriously recommend using a `set` if your items are hashable, because faster and sets already enforce uniqueness.